# Looping through specific values on a table and insert new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
ID, UserID, CompanyID, AccountID, Year1, Month1
```

I need to insert 10 rows to each `AccountID`, is there a way to loop through all `AccountID`s and to insert for each one of them the following values?

```
INSERT INTO Perms (UserID, CompanyID, AccountID, Year1, Month1)
VALUES
    (175, 74,x,2017,3),
    (175, 74,x,2017,4),
    (175, 74,x,2017,5),
    (175, 74,x,2017,6),
    (175, 74,x,2017,7),
    (175, 74,x,2017,8),
    (175, 74,x,2017,9),
    (175, 74,x,2017,10),
    (175, 74,x,2017,11),
    (175, 74,x,2017,12)
```

I have about 100 `AccountID`s and I need some sort of a loop.

Is that doable?

Comment: are you storing the accoutid in any tables and then inserting that to the Perms table? and what are the values that will be changed for each row?

Comment: Are the account ID values continuous?

Comment: are you looking for CROSS JOIN ?

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh No, in the table `perns` I have many `CompanyID`s each `CompanyID` has many `AccountID`s, I need to loop through all the `AccountID`s of a spesific `CompanyID` and insert these 10 rows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No...

Comment: So, you are duplicating all other information except the month on the same table, is that correct ?

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh That's correct, but each time (each 10 rows) with a different `AccountID`

Comment: please add your sample data and expected output for the same

Answer (score 2):

Use CTEs to represent the account and date sequences.  In the case of the account ID values, we can use a recursive CTE.  Below I arbitrarily generate values from `1` to `100`, though this approach should work with any continuous range.  For the year/month combinations, because there are only 10 we can simply hard code them in a CTE.  Then, use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a cross join of the two CTEs.

```
WITH accounts AS ( 
    SELECT 1 AS account
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT account + 1 
    FROM accounts 
    WHERE account + 1 <= 100
),
cte AS (
    SELECT 2017 AS year, 3 AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2017, 12
)
INSERT INTO Perms (UserID, CompanyID, AccountID, Year1, Month1)
SELECT 175, 74, account, year, month
FROM accounts
CROSS JOIN cte;
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 255);
```

**Edit:**

If your account IDs are not continuous, then continuing with this answer you may just manually list them in a CTE, e.g.

```
WITH accounts AS ( 
    SELECT 71 AS account UNION ALL
    SELECT 74 UNION ALL
    SELECT 78 UNION ALL
    SELECT 112 UNION ALL
    SELECT 119
    -- and others
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `month` is not decalred, how should I declare it?

Comment: Huh?  I did declare `month` in the CTE AFAIK.

Comment: So in the `Account` section, it's still not declared..?

Comment: I think I know what's wrong.  Select _ALL_ of my code starting from `WITH` down to the end of the query and then run it.  You need _both_ CTEs in scope in order for my answer to work.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer, I just want to make sure that I run it correctly.

Comment: @user3378165 Apologies...I actually had a typo in the first CTE.  It has been corrected.

Comment: Thank you! I ran it (just the `SELECT` part) but there is one problem- the `AccountID`s values are not continuous... I need to first select all `AccountID`s from the table and based on that add the rows. (For example the `AccountID`s are  `71,74,78,112,119` etc.. (Not starting from `0` end ending by`100`)

Comment: You may try listing the account IDs individually in a CTE, see my updated answer.  Not the most graceful solution, but if there is no clean order/logic to the account IDs then this seems reasonable for a small number of accounts.

Comment: Do you have the accounts listed somewhere in a flat file?  You could import that file into a table and then use it.  Or, if you could somehow select these IDs from another table we could use that.  Barring these options, I'm afraid you will have to list them out by hand in the CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is very similair to already existing answer, but more compact:

```
;with cte as (
  select 175 [UserID], 74 [CompanyID], 2017 [Year1], 3 [Month1]
  union all
  select 175 [UserID], 74 [CompanyID], 2017 [Year1], [Month1] + 1 from cte
  where [Month1] < 12
)
select A.[UserID], A.[CompanyID], B.[AccountID], A.[Year1], A.[Month1] from cte A cross join TABLE_NAME B
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for some reason each row is being selected 10 times, any idea?

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I wanted for each _Account_ to add 10 new rows (with month 3-12), this code actually adds to each Account 100 rows- 10 times each month.

Comment: Well, apply `cross join` only with AccountID's, then join with your base table on this ID :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the accountId's stored in a table and what you want is to insert 10 rows for each account id with Month1 from 3 to 12, try this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Month2 = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Month2+1
        FROM CTE
            WHERE Month2 <12
)
INSERT INTO Perms (UserID, CompanyID, AccountID, Year1, Month1)
SELECT
    UserID = 175, 
    CompanyID ='X', 
    AccountID = YAT.AccountID, 
    Year1 = 2017, 
    Month1 = CTE.Month2
    FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN YourAccountTable YAT
            ON CTE.Month2 BETWEEN 3 AND 12
```

Change the between clause if you want diffrent values